# Как перенести хостинг на новый домен?

Tags: битрикс, веб-сервер, хостинг, битрикс24

У компании есть 3 домена на nic.ru. Один просроченный, нужно сайт который хостится на нем, перенести на новый домен. И есть третий домен, на котором находится сайт который к делу отношения не имеет. Нужно сайт 1 перенести на домен 3. [image: Нужно сайт 1 перенести на домен 2]

Сайт, хранится на сервере. На новый домен нужно перенести именно myslap.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я указал в настройках DNS-хостинга 3-го сайта все те же DNS зоны что и у 1. Но почему-то когда открываешь новый домен, грузится сайт 2, который как я указал выше, к делу отношения не имеет. В чем может быть проблема? Т.е. на новом домене должен подгружаться сайт myslap, а загружается default. Не понимаю в чем дело.